# GroupBy Count using Pandas Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark, anaconda

I know how to do this Scala Spark - I wonder why it's so painful in Anaconda -Python

I want to do an identical operation in Python

```
val dfs = df.groupBy($"col1").count.orderBy(desc("count"))
```

This is giving error

```
dfs = df[['col1']].groupby(['col1]).count.sort(['count'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.size()` and `.sort_values()`.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"col1": np.random.randint(11, 20, size=100, dtype=int)})
dfs = df.groupby('col1').size().sort_values()
print(dfs)
```

Output:

```
col1
16     7
11     8
15     8
12     9
14    11
19    12
13    13
17    16
18    16
dtype: int64
```